# Кроссбраузерная центровка div-а в div-е

Tags: html, css, javascript

Как это сделеать?

Структура такая:

```
<div style="500px">
    <div> размер, в зависимости от текста внутри. этот див нужно центрировать</div>
</div>
```

Comment: С помощью margin'ов и процентного соотношения)

Comment: "margin: 0 auto" чем не угодил? PS: style="500px" - интересненько)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
<div style="width: 500px">
    <div style="max-width:400px; margin: auto">блабла</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант на JQuery:

HTML:

```
<div id="outer" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <div id="inner">Где я?</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#inner {
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    background:#EEE;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = $("#inner");
    var o = $("#outer");
    i.css("marginLeft", (o.width() - i.width()) / 2);    
    i.css("marginTop", (o.height() -i.height()) / 2);    
});
```

Comment: А без js, видимо, никак, да? Вариант с table только остаётся...

Answer (score 1):

никак, если не задать ширину внутреннего дива.
Может подойти(в зависимости от контекста)

```
<div style="width: 500px; text-align: center;">
    <div> размер, в зависимости от текста внутри. этот див нужно центрировать</div>
```